# p:commandButton update doesn't work in ui:include

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I want to update a part of a page by PPR.
This is the part of page that i want to update:

```
 <h:panelGroup id="aggiungiAuto"
                  rendered="#{!autoBean.operazioneOk}">
        <ui:include src="../component/aggiungi_auto.xhtml"/>
 </h:panelGroup>
```

While this is the commandButton present in aggiungi_auto.xhtml

```
 <p:commandButton value="Submit"
                  update="growl aggiungiAuto aggiungiFoto"
                  actionListener="#{autoBean.insert}"/>
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JS/Ajax works on the client side, not on the server side. JSF works on the server side, not on the client side. When you instruct JSF to not render the component to HTML, then nothing will be present in the client side, so JS/Ajax will be unable to locate the HTML element to refresh/update.

You need to wrap it in another `<h:panelGroup>`.

```
<h:panelGroup id="aggiungiAuto">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!autoBean.operazioneOk}">
        <ui:include src="../component/aggiungi_auto.xhtml"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

This way the `<span id="aggiuniAuto">` is *always* present in the client side, so JS/Ajax will be able to update it with the new HTML data generated by JSF.

Answer (score 3):

So I was having this kind of a problem with PrimeFaces (the above answer not being sufficient this time), and I also discovered a solution.

Part of the problem I think was that I was using `ui:include` recursively. For whatever reason, PrimeFaces was irrationally causing UI components to be bound to the backend data out-of-sync; e.g., when an "Add" button was clicked, a new value would be created in the UI, but then the data for it would be ripped out of the values for the section below, etc...

---

The explanation? "[O]n a viewscoped bean, a hidden field is added to the form to hold post-back data[;] if that field is not included with the process, then the bean will lose context." This particular problem is prevalent with `ui:include` recursion especially. **Solution** (all regarding the `p:commandButton` or other actionable component):

- Ensure that `update` and `process` are pointing to a JSF component, not a regular HTML component.
- `update` the next scope up if it breaks (goes out-of-sync with the binding).
- Use `styleClass`'s for update (not e.g. PF ID's or `@this:@parent` kind of stuff), so that jQuery is utilized instead of PF, e.g.: `@(.fieldset-class)`.
- `process` whatever scope is being updated. (This is needed for the post-back data so that the Bean keeps its context for the update...) `process="@this"` is not needed here, provided that the button is contained by the process value component.
- For all buttons without validation wanted, set `immediate="true"`.
- If none of the above works (which happened with the Add buttons, probably due to `ui:include` recursion), set `process="@this"`, `immediate="true"`, and `update="@none"`, and then `oncomplete="remoteCommandName();"`, and have a `p:remoteCommand` instead with that name with the `process`, `immediate`, and `update` mentioned in the above points.
- If none of the above works (which happened with some other buttons, probably due to being yet another layer deeper in the `ui:include` recursion)... wrap a `h:panelGroup` around the next `c:forEach` up and then update the **PrimeFaces ID** of that in the *button* itself while keeping its `remoteCommand` call afterwards, as specified above.
- If none of the above works (which happened yet again to me)... Try the following code:

  - In the `p:commandButton(s)`: `oncomplete="$('.FixButtonSC').click();"`
  - In the `p:fieldset` with a style class of FieldsetSC:

```
          <!-- Fix (hidden) button. -->
          <p:commandButton id="FixButton" styleClass="FixButtonSC"
            process="@this" update="@(.FieldsetSC)" style="display: none;" />
```

Hope that helps...