# Rendered attribute in PrimeFaces

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to have a group of components that are rendered only when a certain condition is met. Something like this:

```
<p:ajax event="select" update=":containerEditorForm:eventTabs:actionProperties"/>

...

<p:column>
    <p:outputPanel id="actionProperties">
        <p:outputPanel rendered="#{commandBean.eventList.activationActionTree.selectedNode ne null}">
            <p:message>message1</p:message>
            <p:message>message2</p:message>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:column>
```

The above solution works fine, but is it really necessary to have two `outputPanel` components, or some other container components, to make this possible? (The outer panel having the `id` attribute, and the inner panel having the `rendered` attribute.) Ideally, I would use `id` and `rendered` in the same element, but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: look here for a detailed explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573190/jsf-primefaces-update-attribute-does-not-update-component

Answer (score 1):

You use JSF tag for rendering component like as i mention this is work with id.

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.id > 0}" id="hello">
```

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking. Check the duplicate question link which Daniel has posted.