# Primefaces 4. How to update elements outside p:tabView

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Let's say there are two tabs. I want to show a button below p:tabView if the user is on the first page and on the other hand I want to not to render that button if the user is on the second page. How can I ahieve this functionality?
My code:

```
<h:form id="fr">
    <p:tabView id="tabV" activeIndex="#{mngr.tabIndex}">
        <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{mngr.onTabChanged}" update=":fr:button"/>
        <p:tab>
            Tab one
        </p:tab>

        <p:tab>
            Tab two
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
    <p:commandButton id="button" rendered="#{mngr.tabIndex == 0}"/>
</h:form>
```

Button is rendered whether you are on first or second tab, however things get differet if you manually refresh the page, then button rendering is working as intended. How can I update that button on tab change event?

Comment: did you try update="button"? It should work.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but it can not find element with id "button".

Comment: I dint see the rendered attribute.. You should wrap your commandbutton inside another element which is always available and use its ID.

Comment: This answer will give a clearer idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573190/jsf-primefaces-update-attribute-does-not-update-component

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ajax update/render does not work on a component which has rendered attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790014/ajax-update-render-does-not-work-on-a-component-which-has-rendered-attribute)

Answer (score 1):

For me, the item was just not being rendered at the time that I was trying to update. You could simply update whatever container is holding the other control (or add one to update as the comment above stated).

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo) is similar and has information on this as well.