# Primefaces updates

Tags: java, primefaces

Hello I'am having problems with updates, I have some composite component nested in few components and i want to update some of them, what is proper way ? Second can i update div?

Code example:

```
<div id="outer">
    <p:commandButton id="button"/>
    <div id="inner">
        <h:form id="form">
             <mycomponents:test whatToUpdate="form panel button outer label">//here problem
        </h:form>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="outer2">
     <h:form id="form">
         <p:panelGroup id="panel">
             <p:label id="label" value="value"/>
         </p:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of divs use **p:outputPanel**:

```
<p:outputPanel id="outer">
    <p:commandButton id="button" update="inner"/>
    <p:outputPanel id="inner">
        <h:form id="form">
             <mycomponents:test whatToUpdate="form panel button outer label">//here problem
        </h:form>
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Ye sure, but I got problem how to call thoose id of components 
"form panel button outer label" because not all are seen from view

Comment: Second I can't update divs? I have problem cause i got always stack trace when i put div id in update

Answer (score 0):

I found some easy way for updating nested components ( i think so ) and i hope that someone will find this usefull. 
The idea is to set styleClass to primefaces component ( dont know some random styleClass name ) and update component using that styleClass.
For example:

```
...bla bla nested components
<p:panel id="somePanel" styleClass="somePanelStyle">
`... bla bla nested components`
<p:panel>
... bla bla nested components
```

any if you need to update it ( in this example panel with id "somePanel") via button for example:

```
<p:commanButton update="@(.somePanelStyle)"
```

Currently im only using this way because its easy to implements update and search (CTRL+H in eclipse) where is that component.

About updating divs, BalusC got some nice answer:
[Answer about updating divs from JSF by BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4574266/2354965)

Answer (score 0):

Before to show my answer I would like to do some assumption:

- First of all you use the same identifier for both `h:form` and this is an error
- I don't know what exactly represents `whatToUpdate` into your composite but I guess it is bound to some `update` attribute.
- I suppose that `form` value inside `whatToUpdate` attribute of your composite component references the outer one.
- inside `JSF` context I don't recommend you to use div, the only place where i would put them is `HTML` template code.
- in `JSF` context I don't recommend you to update element outside `h:form` component, especially if your `p:commandButton` is a submit button.
- I noticed that you would like update only components into two sub-tree, if you put everything inside a `h:form` will be more easy update each components inside the sub-tree just using form referencing.

This is my this is what I would do in your place:

```
<h:form id="form1">
  <p:outputPanel id="outer">
    <p:commandButton id="button"/>
    <p:outputPanel id="inner">
         <mycomponents:test whatToUpdate="@form :form2">
    </p:outputPanel>
  </p:outputPanel>
</h:form>

<h:form id="form2">
  <p:outputPanel id="outer2">
     <p:panelGroup id="panel">
         <p:label id="label" value="value"/>
     </p:panelGroup>
  </p:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

In this way you will update each component of `form1` and `form2` in the easiest way possible and you not have to worry anymore if you would add some components in one of the sub-trees.

Let me know if I wrong some assumption.