# Primefaces dynamic dialog with ui:include not working after PF upgrade from 4.0 to 5.1

Tags: dynamic, jsf-2, primefaces, modal-dialog, uiinclude

I've recently upgraded Primefaces from 4.0 to 5.1 and after that dialogs are not being shown after clicking the commandButton. It works with dynamic="false" but I need it to be lazy loaded. ExampleBean is sessionScoped and i'm using JSF 2.2. Can someone help me solve this?

```
<ui:composition template="/template/common/pagelayout.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:ez="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite">

    <ui:define name="content">    
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:commandButton type="button" value="Log" onclick="PF('dlgLog').show();" icon="botaoLog" />
        </h:form>

        <p:dialog header="HEADER" widgetVar="dlgLog" resizable="false" modal="true" height="500" width="1000" dynamic="true">
            <ui:include src="logPage.xhtml"/>
        </p:dialog>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

logPage.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

  <h:head>
  </h:head>

  <h:body>
    <h:form id="formlog">
        <p:dataTable var="log" value="#{exampleBean.logs}" emptyMessage="Empty">

            <p:column headerText="Header1" width="10%">  
                <h:outputText value="#{log.date}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm"/>
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Header2" width="10%">  
                <h:outputText value="#{log.op}" />  
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Header3">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{log.name}"/>
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you should make it ui:composition : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets

Comment: Thanks @JaqenH'ghar . Tried to make it ui:composition but it didn't work. I can see by the hibernate generated sql in console that the content in page logPage.xhtml is loaded from db but the dialog still not being shown.

Comment: See my answer here; related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53015102/1599699

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured what the problem was. Just removed the `<h:head>` tag from logPage.xhtml and it worked! Not sure I know the reason though, probably has something to do with `<ui:include>` expecting a composition which shouldn't have a `<h:head>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

More specifically, you removed the h:head tag ([and I found out ;-](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=40914#p129144)). Between the versions you used, PF created it's own h:head renderer which differs from the default implementions in code jsf libraries hence the difference in behaviour (assuming your jsf impl stayed the same).

Comment: Thanks again @Kukeltje! Didn't know about the primefaces's h:head renderer! I'll check it out.